# magento 2.2.5 import impossible 1 row 1 product gives error Unable to unserialize value

Tags: magento2.2

I'm running magento 2.2.5. All fine except the import not working.
I try to import, check data, all ok it says.I Then click on import and gives me 
"General system exception happened" Unable to unserialize value.

The file I try to import is an export of the products and then only leave one row without any changes.

Check test.csv file on https://files.fm/u/xpat3a7q#_

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: csv is not downloading

Comment: https://files.fm/u/xpat3a7q#_

Comment: its imported fine just need to change images column path from /p/l/plafondbeugel.jpg to /plafondbeugel.jpg and put that image plafondbeugel.jpg in pub/media/import

Comment: thanks, but all my images are in /pub/media/catalog/product/, like thousands of them in different folders. Why will it not work if i put /pub/media/catalog/product/ as image file directory?

Comment: in this location /pub/media/catalog/product/ all images goes after import done but if you are importing images with product magento read images from /pub/media/import directory

Comment: Ok clear. Thanks. But what is the best way for me then? I want to export my whole products .csv, get rid of some faults (double rows same product, edit special prices etc.). The only way to get rid of the double rows with same sku, is to import with option delete right? So that the new csv is imported as new and not adding or replacing. Should i then cut and paste all the images with folders from pub/media/catalog/product to pub/media/import?

Comment: just create new csv with those columns only which you want to update like as sku , price etc don't use other columns which you don't want to update.

Comment: Yes but then the faulty double rows with same sku will not be deleted.